# slider not working

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

can you guys tell me why my slider is not working 
i have included all the resources in the js fiddle then also its not working
providing fiddle link below

http://jsfiddle.net/YakV7/2/

actual demo

http://tympanus.net/Development/ParallaxContentSlider/

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.cslider.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {

                $('#da-slider').cslider();

            });
        </script>
```

Comment: You aren't including the `jquery.cslider.js` properly.  Try using an absolute path instead of a relative one.  Also check your javascript errors when javascript doesn't work.

Comment: can you tell me what path should i put to male it work

Comment: Everything works correctly here http://jsfiddle.net/YakV7/6/

Comment: @user1914176 See the working fiddle in my answer. `:)` And I mean **Everything, including images**! `:)`

Comment: thanks for your reply i am trying to achieve css3 slider animation similar to ibm but i dont wat seconds to give in animation to achieve similar to ibm http://www.ibm.com/us/en/

Comment: .da-slide-fromright
.da-slide-fromleft
.da-slide-toright
.da-slide-toleft this are the classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What do you mean by these lines?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/demo.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/modernizr.custom.28468.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.cslider.js"></script>
```

#### Change it to the actual path.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://tympanus.net/Development/ParallaxContentSlider/css/demo.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://tympanus.net/Development/ParallaxContentSlider/css/style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://tympanus.net/Development/ParallaxContentSlider/js/modernizr.custom.28468.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://tympanus.net/Development/ParallaxContentSlider/js/jquery.cslider.js"></script>
```

#### Or add:

```
<base href="http://tympanus.net/Development/ParallaxContentSlider/" />
```

#### Same working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YakV7/7/

Comment: Use the `<base href="http://tympanus.net/Development/ParallaxContentSlider/" />` inside your `<head>`. I **won't** recommend it and it will be better to host the files in your site. The path is `http://tympanus.net/Development/ParallaxContentSlider/`.

Comment: thanks for your reply i am trying to achieve css3 slider animation similar to ibm but i dont wat seconds to give in animation to achieve similar to ibm ibm.com/us/en

Comment: @user1914176 Should be `400` milliseconds or in css `0.4s`

Comment: .da-slide-fromright
.da-slide-fromleft
.da-slide-toright
.da-slide-toleft this are the classes